# Hide multiple divs onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to hide all visible divs and toggle one onclick of a single button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

Right Now I have three buttons in a table with:

```
<a class="stream" style="display:none">
<center>
<iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/g4ivl3_0v3r/embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" height="700px" width="65%"></iframe>
<br>
<iframe src="http://www.twitch.tv/g4ivl3_0v3r/chat?popout=" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" height="300" width="65%"></iframe>
</center>
</div>
```

under the toggle button:

```
<img src="images/twitch.png"
  width="20%" height="20%" border="0" onclick="toggle_visibility('stream')">
```

So I'm just wondering if with what I'm currently working with can hide all other divs on the page and toggle just the one, or two. Right now the above works fine in moving my table down and showing the div I want but in the end Id like to hide it all except for the stream div.

Also, I'm sort of new at this as I'm sure you can tell but I'm trying to learn what I can. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: My suggestion is to try to learn the jQuery selectors, you can select any thing by name, id, class,... and ask jQuery to do what you want hide, show, move ....

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this:

```
$('div').hide();// hide all divs

$("#stream").show();// here show the div with id stream
```

if you want to show all the div's with class strean use the below.

```
$(".stream").show();// here show the div with class stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
$("div:visible").hide();
```

... to hide all visible DIVs.  Then, turn on the one that shouldn't be hidden ...

```
$(".stream").show();
```

Comment: SyntaxError, you have not closed the double-quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button_id").click(function(){
     $('div').hide(); //this will hide all the div(s) firstly
     $("#stream").show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#selector").click(function(){
     $('div').hide(); //this will hide all the div
     $("#stream").show(); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use jQuery, try:

```
function toggle(elem, collection) {
    var shown = (elem.style.display === 'block');

    for (i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
        if (!shown) {
            collection[i].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            collection[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }

    if (shown) {
        elem.style.display = '';
    } else {
        elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

toggle(document.getElementById('stream'), document.getElementsByTagName('div'));
```

Assuming `#stream` is set to `display: none;` using CSS instead of inline styling. Otherwise change `''` to `'none'`.